# deploy с помошью docker-compose и gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, развертывание, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Как лучше сделать deploy использую gitlab-ci и `docker-compose.yml`

На данный момент был 1 контейнер и deploy сейчас идет по SSH:

```
ssh core@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker login -u ${PROD_USER} -p ${PROD_PASS} registry.gitlab.com;
      docker pull registry.gitlab.com/user_name/ffbot:latest;
      docker stop ffbot && docker rm ffbot;
      sudo mkdir -p /srv/ffbot/db;
      docker run -it -d --name ffbot -p 443:8000
        -v /srv/ffbot/db:/home/fbbot/db
        -e PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN=$PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
        -e VERIFY_TOKEN=$VERIFY_TOKEN
        -e S3_BUCKET=$S3_BUCKET
        -e S3_KEY=$S3_KEY
        -e S3_SECRET=$S3_SECRET
        -e S3_LOCATION=$S3_LOCATION
          registry.gitlab.com/user_name/ffbot:latest"
```

Но в случаи docker-compose я не понимаю как можно развернуть проект не загружая по ssh `docker-compose.yml` или клонирую сего репозитория ради 1 docker-compose, есть рекомендуемый способ для этой задачи? (желательно для gitlab-ci но это не критично)

Есть вот такой решения, но не уверен в его правильности ([ссылка на статью](https://medium.com/@codingfriend/continuous-integration-and-deployment-with-gitlab-docker-compose-and-digitalocean-6bd6196b502a)):

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: gitlab/dind:latest
  only:
    - "master"
  environment: production
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$DEPLOY_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H $DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - printf "DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}\nPORT=80\n" > environment.env
    - scp -r ./environment.env ./docker-compose.autodeploy.yml root@${DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP}:~/
    - root@$DEPLOYMENT_SERVER_IP "docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY};
       docker-compose -f docker-compose.autodeploy.yml stop;
       docker-compose -f docker-compose.autodeploy.yml rm web --force;
       docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}:latest;
       docker-compose -f docker-compose.autodeploy.yml up -d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Недавно мне приходилось решать аналогичную задачу и вот что могу сказать по этому поводу.

Как такового "рекомендуемого" способа для развертывания не нашел. Однако, исходя из практики удаленного управления docker-ом, нет необходимости заходить на production-сервер по ssh. Можно применить следующий алгоритм:

1) На production-машине настраиваете возможность управления docker-ом "из-вне"

2) В .gitlab-ci.yml выполняете обычные команды docker-compose, например `up -d`, с учетом установки переменных окружения:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$PRODUCTION_HOST:2376
```

При выполнении шага 1 Вы столкнетесь с генерацией т.н. TLS сертификатов, которые обеспечивают безопасное соединение и  которые впоследствии должны будут скопированы на машину, с которой будет осуществляться управление. Эти же сертификаты должны быть доступны при развертывании через CI.

В моем случае, развертывание осуществляет специальный контейнер, который предварительно из файлового хранилища скачивает сертификаты и файлы окружения, и потом, уже удаленно, выполняет загрузку образов из docker registry на сервер и перезапускает контейнеры.  В качестве файлового хранилища использую https://minio.io. Естественно, "специальный" контейнер должен предварительно скачать клиента *minio* чтобы иметь возможность оперировать файлами.

Учитывая "громоздкость" процедуры в .gitlab-ci.yml я прописываю вызов shell-сценария

Файл .gitlab-ci.yml (фрагмент)

```
...
deploy:
  stage: deploy

  image: "jonaskello/docker-and-compose"

  script:
    - bin/ci_deploy.sh

  only:
    - develop
```

Файл bin/ci_deploy.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -e
set -v

# --- Minio
# MCI образ клиента minio, нужен для работы с файловым хранилищем
# MS - URL хоста файлового хранилища
# MINIO_USER=secret variable
# MINIO_PASSWORD=secret variable
# --- Docker
# DOCKER_DRIVER=overlay2
# DOCKER_REGISTRY - URL для docker registry
# DOCKER_PASSWORD=secret variable
# --- Debug
# CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=release

DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/root/.docker
STAGING_HOST=192.168.1.100 # ip адрес, куда надо развернуть приложиение

DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.yml
DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=myproject_$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
ENV_FILE=myproject.$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.env

# --- проверяем наличие docker и docker-compose
docker info
docker-compose version

# --- загружаем с файлового хранилища файл окружения compose
#     и сертификаты для удаленного управления docker-ом
docker run --rm \
    -v /cache/.mc:/root/.mc \
    $MCI config host add minio $MS $MINIO_USER $MINIO_PASSWORD

docker run --rm \
    -v /cache/.mc:/root/.mc \
    -v /cache/tmp:/tmp \
    $MCI cp minio/ds4-staging-config/$ENV_FILE /tmp/myproject.env

docker run --rm \
    -v /cache/.mc:/root/.mc \
    -v /cache/tmp:/tmp \
    $MCI find minio/docker-certs --name "*.pem" --exec "mc cp {} /tmp"

cp /cache/tmp/myproject.env myproject.env

mkdir -p $DOCKER_CERT_PATH

cp /cache/tmp/*.pem $DOCKER_CERT_PATH

# --- запускаем развертывание

export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://$STAGING_HOST:2376

docker-compose \
    --file $DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE \
    --project-name $DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME \
    ps

docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD $DOCKER_REGISTRY

docker-compose \
    --file $DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE \
    --project-name $DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME \
    pull api

docker-compose \
    --file $DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE \
    --project-name $DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME \
    up -d

docker-compose \
    --file $DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE \
    --project-name $DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME \
    exec -T api bin/rails db:migrate:status

docker-compose \
    --file $DOCKER_COMPOSE_FILE \
    --project-name $DOCKER_COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME \
    exec api bin/rails db:migrate
```

**Обновление 2017-07-25**

[Инструкция по настройке удаленного управления Docker-ом на Ubuntu Sever](https://gist.github.com/nmix/be7782814ad6753e6f1d54d2299b93a0)

Comment: огромное спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ @Nik ссылка по настройки Docker:

- [coreos.com](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-docker.html) - настройка Docker для CoreOS (и для удаленного управления)

---

<sup>считаю удобнее вынести это в отдельный ответ что-бы была возможность дополнить ответ дополнительными ссылками</sup>